# Differences in one column based on differences in another, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, pandas-groupby, timedelta

How can I perform the below manipulation with `pandas`?

I have this dataframe :

```
weight   |  Date                  |  dateDay
43       | 09/03/2018  08:48:48   |  09/03/2018
30       | 10/03/2018  23:28:48   |  10/03/2018
45       | 12/03/2018  04:21:44   |  12/03/2018
25       | 17/03/2018  00:23:32   |  17/03/2018
35       | 18/03/2018  04:49:01   |  18/03/2018
39       | 19/03/2018  20:14:37   |  19/03/2018
```

I want this :

```
weight   |  Date                  |  dateDay     |  Fun_Cum
43       | 09/03/2018  08:48:48   |  09/03/2018  |    NULL
30       | 10/03/2018  23:28:48   |  10/03/2018  |    -13
45       | 12/03/2018  04:21:44   |  12/03/2018  |    NULL
25       | 17/03/2018  00:23:32   |  17/03/2018  |    NULL
35       | 18/03/2018  04:49:01   |  18/03/2018  |     10
39       | 19/03/2018  20:14:37   |  19/03/2018  |      4
```

Pseudo code:

If Day does not follow Day-1 => Fun_Cum is NULL;

Else  (weight day) - (weight day-1)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html). You can take the difference between consecutive `datetime` elements and access [`pd.Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) attribute.

```
df['Fun_Cum'] = df['weight'].diff()

df.loc[(df.dateDay - df.dateDay.shift()).dt.days != 1, 'Fun_Cum'] = np.nan

print(df)

   weight       Date    dateDay  Fun_Cum
0      43 2018-03-09 2018-03-09      NaN
1      30 2018-03-10 2018-03-10    -13.0
2      45 2018-03-12 2018-03-12      NaN
3      25 2018-03-17 2018-03-17      NaN
4      35 2018-03-18 2018-03-18     10.0
5      39 2018-03-19 2018-03-19      4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#import pandas as pd
#from datetime import datetime
#to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')
#df = pd.read_csv('d.csv', converters={'dateDay': to_datetime})
```

Above part only if you reading from the file, else its just .shift() what u need

```
a = df
b = df.shift()
df["Fun_Cum"] = (a.weight - b.weight) * ((a.dateDay - b.dateDay).dt.days ==1)
```

Comment: Won't you have to replace `0` with `NaN` at the end of this?